# push increment item into an array in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/NDTgTaTO1xT7bLS1FALN?p=preview

```
<button ng-click="addRow()">add row</button>

<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"><input type="tel" placeholder="tel">
</div>
```

I want to push new row and save all the fields but now I'm stuck at adding new rows. How to know the current number of row and do increment to push into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example I created which allows you to generate up to eight unique input fields for `Telephone` and `Text` Entries.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.rows = [];
  
var Row = function(tel, text) {
  // Private data
  var private = {
    tel: tel,
    text: text
  }

  // Expose public API
  return {
    get: function( prop ) {
      if ( private.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        return private[ prop ];
      }
    }
  }
};

  $scope.addRow = function(){
    
    if($scope.rows.length < 8){
      var newItemNum = $scope.rows.length + 1;
      var row = new Row('item' + newItemNum, 'item' + newItemNum);
      
      $scope.rows.push(row);
    }
  };
  
  $scope.saveAll = function(){
  //  $scope.result = 'something';
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      <h2>Setting</h2>
      <button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
      <br />
    
      <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text" ng-model="row.textModel" >
        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="row.telModel" >
      </div>
    
      <br />
      {{rows}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the public API for?

Comment: Encapsulate your data, It restricts access and allows you to retrieve private data from within the method by accessing the `public api`. In this case is simply a `get` property per say. Read up on JS Private Members here: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/14/javascript-how-to-get-private-privileged-public-and-static-members-properties-and-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Move functions inside controller 'Ctrl'.

In your script:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.result = "something";
    $scope.rows = ['1'];

    $scope.addRow = function(){
        if ($scope.rows.length < 8) {
            $scope.rows.push($scope.rows.length + 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.saveAll = function(){
    //  $scope.result = 'something';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need only 2 rows?

Comment: For example. See changes.

Comment: thanks! u really helpful, but what if I change $scope.row to json array? will $scope.row.length + 1 still work?

Comment: I think, yes. Anyway you can use `JSON.parse` to convert to array.